# Validation Output Error: there is no attribute "leftmargin"

Tags: html

**there is no attribute "leftmargin"**

```html
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheig…
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
```

Not sure what's wrong, any tips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`leftmargin` was a non-standard extension to HTML by a browser vendor. It was never standardised because CSS came along (almost two decades ago now). Since it isn't standard, it doesn't form part of the XHTML 1.0 Transitional DTD.

Use CSS instead (for all of the attributes you have on your body start tag in that example).

- [Introduction to CSS](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Web_Standards_Curriculum#CSS) (W3C)
- [Getting started guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started) (MDN)
- [margin property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) (MDN)
- [background-color property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color) (MDN)

NB: The Transitional DTD was provided as a middle point to help migrate from HTML 3.2 to the Strict DTD. You probably shouldn't still be using it. For that matter, it might be wise to move all the way to HTML 5 (which reached Recommendation status last year).

Answer (score 1):

Change your code:

```
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheig…
```

Use CSS instead to style your webpage:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background: #FFFFFF;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use css `style="margin-left:0px;"`